# Unity action passed as argument without ref keyword doesn't execute subscribed method, while with ref keyword it does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, arguments, ref

Left class instantiates right class and passes 2 arguments, transform ( which isn't used) and unity action that gets called from the right class. Left class that receives unity action subscribes to it and should call OnFinished when that unity action gets executed from the right class.

This happens only if unity action is passed with ref keyword
Why it doesn't work if there is no ref keyword.

I tried subscribing to that unity action before passing it as argument. But that doesn't work either. only Ref keyword does the job.

[image]

Comment: Your design is _back-to-front._  Irrespective of what the classes are called and the technique used for firing events/invoking delegates, one class has an event the other is subscribing to however _the publisher of the event has to call the subscriber in order to setup the subscription_ (all that `Setup()` stuff).  That's counter intuitive. We know which one is the publisher of the events because it's the one with the `.Invoke()`.   The subscriber (`PointingArrowWorker`) should be the one calling into the other via a `Subscribe()` call.

Comment: ....apart from that you really want to avoid delegates/event-subscriptions because it's one of the few places in .NET that can lead to a memory leak if you forget to perform a `-=` unsubscribe **OR** if two classes reference each other (as you are doing).   Why the need for all this anyway?

Comment: @MickyD good point, this was setup so that publisher can call hint system where to put an arrow to guide the player to the object, but didn't want to keep the reference of that object so I wanted to pass the event so spawned arrow can listen when the publisher has finished and self destroy. The concept works when I use ref keyword, and fails without it, and I want to know why? 

Also I use in many places same thing only the spawned class invokes callback on complete to the publisher and that works without ref keyword. I'm interested in what is going on and why it can't work like this. Thanks

Comment: To explain my thoughts, Hint system (singleton) is spawning arrows on a position on demand, those arrows need to be destroyed when the caller has completed whatever he had. In the example above I excluded the singleton stuff and just made a direct instantiation of the pointerArrow by the publisher. 
This all was meant to work by passing the unity action to pointer arrow as argument which poniterarrow should listen and know when the publisher has completed and self destroy. 
My question is why is this not working when passing unityAction, but working when passing ref UnityAction?

Comment: _"so that publisher can call hint system where to put an arrow to guide the player to the object, but didn't want to keep the reference of that object"_ - Ah...sort of like a weak-reference in an event model.  "weak" as in _pointing to something without preventing the object to be garbage collected_.   Kewl.   At the moment I have no explanation for the `ref` bit tho.  :(    Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD just something I wanted to test out quickly, but the system is far from production ready. Will probably change it to something a lot more elegant and straight forward, but the ref thing kept me here and really gave me an itch.... Thanks for the discussion tho.